# Question in the proof of existence of finite fields

Tags: field-theory

In the proof (In Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Existence_and_uniqueness and Dummit Foote p.549) of the existence of finite fields (Using splitting field of $x^{p^n}-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$), they show the collection of roots is actually the splitting field by showing that the sum and product of the roots are again a root and multiplicative inverse is again a root. As far as I know, we need to show the subtraction of two elements is again in the given set (In this case, the set of roots) to show the given set has group structure. Why in this case the $\textit{sum}$ of two roots is again root is enough?

Comment: Because $x-y=x+(p-1)y$.

Comment: Oh, that was a really stupid question. Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively: $-1$ is itself a root of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b$ satisfy $x^{p^n} = x$.

Then $$0^{p^n} = 0.$$

And $$1^{p^n} = 1.$$

And $$(a \cdot b)^{p^n} = a^{p^n} \cdot b^{p^n}.$$

If $a \not = 0$ then define $a^{-1} = a^{p^n-1}$ and $$(a^{-1})^{p^n} = (a^{p^{n}-1})^{p^n} = (a^{p^n})^{p^{n}-1} = a^{-1}$$

And $$(a + b)^{p^n} = a^{p^n} + p \cdot (\cdots) + b^{p^n} = a^{p^n} + b^{p^n} = a + b.$$

Since the set is finite and we have addition we also have subtraction. Alternatively you can see that $-1$ is a root (even in the special case of $p=2$).

Therefore these roots form a field.